# MySQL Join query with group is taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables **orders** and **order_items** the order table contains the basic details of order like customer delivery details etc and the order_items table contains all the product-related data of the corresponding order.

Now I am using following SQL query to list orders however it is taking too long to return results while I have also created indexed for the necessary columns.

```sql
SELECT orders.order_number, orders.firstname, orders.lastname FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_items USING ON orders.order_number = order_items.order_number
WHERE (((orders.firstname LIKE '%%') OR (orders.lastname LIKE '%%'))) AND orders.store_id = '3' AND order_items.sku = 'SHHDW-32'
GROUP BY orders.order_number
ORDER BY orders.date_added DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

I found on search online that the reason is due to grouping with join and it could be solved by replacing join with subquery. So, can anyone please help me with restructuring the query. I need make search in orders and order_items table as per the requirement.

The orders table has 47534 records and order_items table has 55500 and the following query takes  3-4 seconds to return results

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the purpose of this query? Sample data, desired results, and an explanation would all be helpful here.

Comment: Can you also show us the indexes you've created?

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? Did you create multiple indexes?

Comment: The filtering condition `orders.firstname LIKE '%%'` doesn't do anything. Maybe you should omit it.

Comment: Show output of `show create table orders` and `show create table order_items` and `explain select ...rest of your query`

Comment: Probably should learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This query returns an indeterminate result. Probably best to bin it and start over. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query